# Nginx reads file from multiple locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Pardon me, I'm new to nginx, if the question is vague, please point me to some directions.
I have an image `xyz.jpg` in `Disk-1`, and an image `abc.jpg` in `Disk-2`, when I call url:`../image/xyz.jpg`, the `xyz.jpg (Disk-1)` shows up by using `alias` in my nginx's file . Question is:
Is there any way to call `../image/abc.jpg`, the `abc.jpg (Disk-2)` will show up ?

```
location /image/ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            alias  /image_data/;
        }
```

Edit: I used `try_files` but it didn't work

```
        location @image2  {
           alias /image_data_2/;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404
        }

        location /image/ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            alias /image_data/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @image2;
        }
```

Comment: You can use `try_files` to try more than one location. Is there a common directory that can be used as `root` for both disk-1 and disk-2?

Comment: No, it is not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to check two folders for images to match URIs beginning with `/image/`.

You could use a *regular expression* `location` block to capture the part of the URI following the prefix, which avoids using the `alias` directive. The regular expression locations are evaluated in order, so the placement of the block within the `server` block is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Within the protection of the `location` block, the `root` is set to a common parent directory (in this case `/`) and construct the path to the files using `try_files` terms.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/image/(.*)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    root /;
    try_files /image_date/$1 /image_data_2/$1 =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.